# unbootstrap after angular.bootstrap has been initiated?

Tags: angularjs

Having trouble trying to recompile angular app.

Is there a way to unbootstrap after calling angular.bootstrap?

Once I do angular.bootstrap when already bootstrapped, causes errors

Thanks!

Comment: Why exactly would you want to recompile the entire app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does not seem like angular was designed to do this, and I can't think of any good reason why you would want to (but maybe you do). That said, from looking at the [angular.js source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L1414)
 it seems like the only way that this **could** work would be to remove the element you originally bootstrapped from the DOM and then re-add it and then try bootstraping again.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jacktasia/tSVyw/8/) proof of concept that bootstraps a super simple app and then after 5 seconds bootstraps itself again. I'd be extremely hesitant to do something like this on a complex app but it does seem to work.

```
 var bootstrapApp = function(appDiv) {
    var isSecondTime = false;
    if (appDiv) {
        document.body.removeChild(appDiv);
        isSecondTime = true;
    }
    appDiv = document.createElement('div');
    appDiv.id = "myApp";
    appDiv.innerHTML = (isSecondTime ? ' 2nd bootstrap': ' 1st bootstrap') + template.innerHTML;
    document.body.appendChild(appDiv);
    angular.bootstrap(angular.element(appDiv), ['myApp']);

    return appDiv;
}

var createdAppDiv = bootstrapApp(null);

setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("try boostraping again");
    bootstrapApp(createdAppDiv);
}, 5000);
```