# Dynamic Injection of application module dependencies in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a module `qApp`

```
angular
  .module('qApp', [
    'ngCookies',
    'ngRoute'
  ])
```

Later while program is running I dynamically load js scripts that contain other modules (lets call them plugin-modules).

Example:

```
angular
  .module('q-plugin-email', [])
  .constant('name', 'q-plugin-email')
  .factory('factory', [
    function() {
      return {/*...*/}
    }
  ])
  .directive('ui', [
    function() {
      return {/*...*/}
    }
  ]);
```

1. How do I actually add plugins to `qApp` dependency list after the app module was created?
2. Will it be possible to name factory and directive with the same name in every dependant plugin (so it was possible to follow the unique pattern creating plugins)

Comment: I think once the app has been bootstrapped you can only use the dependencies you have. But there are ways to lazy load, read here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6180. You could also manually re-bootstrap the app, maybe it will work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027229/unbootstrap-after-angular-bootstrap-has-been-initiated

Comment: This has happened to me before and I know of a working solution (not mine so i don't take any credits on that). This blog post explains how to do lazy load with RequireJS but the core trick is the same http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2554-loading-angularjs-components-with-requirejs-after-application-bootstrap.htm