# how to remove an Angular App

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on a web-based onepage-application which is written with javascript/jquery. Now i get the order to load an angular.js application to a new menu-section. OK, this is no problem and the angular-app is running after manually bootstrapping. But if i go to another section, i want to completely remove the angular-app to clear the memory.

I tried with `$('#anything').empty()`, but when i try to reload the angular-app i got an error with "App Already Bootstrapped with this Element 'document'". What can i do?

many Thanks
Harald

Comment: Can you maybe clear up your question a bit. Why do you want to 'clear the memory'? Are you planning on loading another application? Are you trying to load another component of the Angular application?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25027614/165674) and the linked [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jacktasia/tSVyw/8/).

Comment: on every click i load an application or tons of data.  so, i think, i have to clean the memory.